# Going through a 2-d array to reach position with integer 0

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to go through a 2-d array and reach the position that has a 0 and I want to print the direction the program has taken to reach the position (North, south, east, west). If it is not possible, I have to return false. Can someone help me. 
Thank you in advance for your help 
Here is the method I created, it has to be recursive:

```
    public static Boolean MagicBoard_recursive(int[][] board, int size, int startRow, int startCol) {
        boolean result = true;
        int number = board[startRow][startCol];
        int destinationNumber;

        while(!result) {
            // If we reach the position that contains the 0
            if(board[startRow][startCol] == 0) {
                System.out.println("We have reached the goal square containing 0.");
                result = true;
                break;
            }           

            // If we can only move in 1 direction, either North, South, East or West
            // Verify if we can only move south
            if((startRow+number) < size && (startRow-number) < 0 && ((startCol+number) > size || (startCol-number) < 0)) {
                destinationNumber = board[startRow+number][startCol];

                // Make sure that the destination position will not make us go back and forth
                if((startRow == (startRow+number-destinationNumber))) {
                    System.out.print("The MagicBoard is unsolvable");
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
                // If don't go back and forth, then we continue
                else {
                    startRow = startRow+number;
                    System.out.print("Move south " + number + ", ");
                    MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                }
            }
            // Verify if we can only move North
            else if((startRow+number) > size && (startRow-number) > 0 && ((startCol+number) > size || (startCol-number) < 0)){
                destinationNumber = board[startRow-number][startCol];
                // Make sure that we won't go back and forth if we go at that position
                if((startRow == (startRow-number+destinationNumber))) {
                    System.out.print("The MagicBoard is unsolvable");
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
                // If don't go back and forth, then we continue
                else {
                    startRow = startRow-number;
                    System.out.print("Move north " + number + ", ");
                    MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                }
            }
            // If can only go east
            else if((startCol+number)<size && (startCol-number)<0 && ((startRow+number)>size || (startRow-number)<0)) {
                destinationNumber = board[startRow][startCol+number];
                // Make sure that we won't go back and forth if we go at that position
                if((startCol == (startCol+number-destinationNumber))) {
                    System.out.print("The MagicBoard is unsolvable");
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
                // If we don't go back and forth, then we continue
                else {
                    startCol = startCol+number;
                    System.out.print("Move east " + number + ", ");
                    MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                }
            }
            // If can't move any other direction that west
            else if((startCol+number) > size && (startCol-number)> 0 && ((startRow+number)>size || (startRow-number)<0)) {
                destinationNumber = board[startRow][startCol-number];
                // Make sure that we won't go back and forth if we go at that position
                if((startCol == (startCol-number+destinationNumber))) {
                    System.out.print("The MagicBoard is unsolvable");
                    result = false; 
                    break;
                }
                // If we don't go back and forth, then we continue
                else {
                    startCol = startCol-number;
                    System.out.print("Move west " + number + ", ");
                    MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                }
            }

            // If we can move any direction
            else {
                // try moving south
                SOUTH:
                    if(startRow-number < 0) {
                        destinationNumber = board[startRow+number][startCol];
                        // Verify if we go back and forth if we go south, if we do, then we the result will be 
                        if((startRow == (startRow+number-destinationNumber))) {
                            break SOUTH;
                        }
                        else {
                            startRow = startRow+number;
                            System.out.print("Move south " + number + ", ");
                            MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                        }
                    }
                NORTH:
                    if(startRow-number > 0) {
                        destinationNumber = board[startRow-number][startCol];
                        if((startRow == (startRow-number+destinationNumber))) {
                            break NORTH;
                        }
                        else {
                            startRow = startRow-number;
                            System.out.print("Move north " + number + ", ");
                            MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // try moving east
                EAST:
                    if(startCol-number<0) {
                        destinationNumber = board[startRow][startCol+number];
                        // If will go back and forth at that position, then we exit the EAST label and we go to the next label
                        if((startCol == (startCol+number-destinationNumber))) {
                            System.out.print("The MagicBoard is unsolvable");
                            break EAST;
                        }
                        else {
                            startCol = startCol+number;
                            System.out.print("Move east " + number + ", ");
                            MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                        }
                    }
                    // Try moving west  
                WEST:
                    if(startCol-number > 0) {
                        destinationNumber = board[startRow][startCol-number];
                        // If we go back and forth in that position, then we exit the EAST label
                        if((startCol == (startCol-number+destinationNumber))) {
                            System.out.print("The MagicBoard is unsolvable");
                            result = false;
                            break WEST;
                        }
                    else {
                        startCol = startCol-number;
                        System.out.print("Move west " + number + ", ");
                        MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example application for you which explains how to "document" the path of your "search".

```
package direction;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

enum DIRECTION {
    NORTH,
    SOUTH,
    WEST,
    EAST
}

public class Direction {
    private static List<DIRECTION> pathway = new ArrayList<DIRECTION>();
    
    public static Boolean MagicBoard_recursive(/* your arguments are here */) {
        /* your program code is here */
        
        /* your program "pointer/searcher" moves NORTH */
        pathway.add(DIRECTION.NORTH);
        /* your program "pointer/searcher" moves SOUTH */
        pathway.add(DIRECTION.SOUTH);
        /* your program "pointer/searcher" moves WEST */
        pathway.add(DIRECTION.WEST);
        /* your program "pointer/searcher" moves EAST */
        pathway.add(DIRECTION.EAST);
        
        /* this way you can see the "path" of your program code */
        for(int i = 0; i < pathway.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(pathway.get(i));
        }
        
        return true; /* this is just a placeholder, use your own return value here */
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MagicBoard_recursive();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble implementing it, but I found another way, I simply used a for loop and created and array that contains all the possible directions that we can go